# Create Page custom animations in Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime)

Tags: animation, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to develop some animations for my pages or my page content. The approach of which one I should follow is unclear to me at the moment and I'll try to explain why.

What I'd like to achieve is to create a page (or page content) animation with a slide-in from right when navigating to the page and slide-out to left when leaving the page.

The slide-in part can be achieved with `ContentThemeTransition` from `TransitionCollection`. But what about the slide-out part?
I can't seem to know or find any good timing regarding when to fire a slide-out animation just before the page is about to be left.

I'dlike not to apply any animation to the page in such way that WP does by default (with some jump-out, jump-in effect). I'd like to be like `BasicPage` from templates with no animation but with custom animated content upon page enter and page leave.

How could this be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are navigating from the page via tapping a button or something similar. Why don't you create a storyboard animation, [start that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx#startingcontrolling) from the Click event handler of the button, and call Frame.Navigate() when the animation has [finished playing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. In the end I used the built-in page animations.

Comment: My issue was that when page animations were performed (they were having light background), I had a different color in the background, which was actually the Frame Background. I just set that to have the same color as my page background and then I used the built-in page animations. In this way I achieved the result I needed.